# Copy PHP file from other URL without executing the code

Tags: php

When I duplicate or copy a PHP file from one url to another, the content within the PHP executes. The php files contain mysqli query's.

I tried 2 methods, the file_get_contents and php's default copy function. Both transfer the file from one to another but both times the copied PHP file shows:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in  <b>/home/uu/domains/domain.net/public_html/library/folder/index.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

Method 1:

```
if ( copy($from.$element_file['file'], $to.$element_file['file']) ) {
    chmod($to.$element_file['file'], 0777);
}
```

Method 2:

```
$content = file_get_contents($from.$element_file['file']); 
$new_file = $to.$element_file['file'];
$handle = fopen($new_file, 'w');
file_put_contents($new_file, $content);
```

Reason:
I'm not trying to hack or steal anything. I've build a external library with files I can use while developing new websites, like little templates (dir with an index.php, less file and a query file). All the php files are on the same server.

Comment: Of course not, perfectly fine PHP. A dot is a combination symbol

Comment: If you could do this then the security of the web site can be compromised. That is why it is not possible.

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Why are you pulling code from one url to another; rather than duplicating the script? If you can update your question to include this, you'll get your answer

Comment: If the files are on the same server, then you should not be using URL's. Using a URL will cause it to execute. Imagine the security implications if you could randomly grab the source code to any script you wanted.

Comment: Managed to find a workaround. I zipped the dir, copied to new url and unzipped it. Not the ideal way to go i guess...

Answer (score 2):

When You copy a **URL** you're  copying server's output for that url!
So the script will execute (as it should execute to generate output).
to copy a file content (script itself) you need to copy it from a file server or other method that give you file output.
If the files are on the same server you should use file path instead of URL.
For an example if you have access you can use CURL to access FTP on the target server and copy the file.